# How to fix: Script Causing Page Refresh (return false; not working)

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript functions. The one shows and hides div's by their ID. This has been working fine until now. I have since added some code I found online that prevents iOS from opening links in a new window (when in fullscreen mode). Since adding this new code everytime I click on a div to show/hide it, the functions fires but then the page refreshes. Any help?

I have tried to put return false in every conceivable place. 
I changed my onclick to 'return function();'.
I changed it to 'function();return false'.
I placed return false inside both functions.

```
(function(document,navigator,standalone) {
    //Code by Irae Carvalho http://about.me/irae
    // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
    // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>

    if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
        var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            curnode=e.target;
            while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                curnode=curnode.parentNode;
            }
            if('href' in curnode ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                location.href = curnode.href;
            }

            return false;

        },false);
    }
})(document,window.navigator,'standalone');

function showHidden(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
        div.style.display = '';
    }else{
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } 
    return false;
}

<!-- The code below is in my php file -->

<a onclick="showHidden('divID')">
```

Clicking on the link fires the showHidden function correctly but then it also refreshes the page. I need the event listener to prevent iOS from opening links in a new window when in fullscreen mode but I also don't want the click listener to fire when I use the showHidden function, or at the least not refresh the page.

Comment: Why are you returning false from these functions? You only need to return something if the line that calls your function is expecting a value. If you don't do anything with the `false` that's returned where the function is called, then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JakeReece - most likely OP is using older IE tutorials. Older IE demands `false` be returned since older IE didn't support `preventDefault()`. Just a guess.

Comment: Yes, I have been searching online for anything that may help. The return false makes no difference whether its there or not.

Comment: If your intent is to allow the use of the _Back_ button, but not actually navigate to the page, you should investigate the History API rather than using `document.href`.

Comment: My itention is to be able to click on a link and display/hide a hidden div.

Comment: Your `return false` doesn't work because it's done from your named function but not from your inline event handler where it's needed

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is changing pages is because you are not preventing the default action of a link click, which is in this case loading a different page. You can do this by invoking `e.preventDefault()` when the link is clicked.

Here is an example:

```js
(function(document,navigator,standalone) {
    //Code by Irae Carvalho http://about.me/irae
    // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
    // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>

    if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
        var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            curnode=e.target;
            while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                curnode=curnode.parentNode;
            }
            if('href' in curnode ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                location.href = curnode.href;
            }

            return false;

        },false);
    }
})(document,window.navigator,'standalone');

function showHidden(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
        div.style.display = '';
    }else{
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } 
    return false;
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
links.forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var divID = this.getAttribute('hide-id');
    showHidden(divID)
  })
})
```

```html
<a hide-id="div1">Click here</a>
<div id="div1">
This is content
</div>

<br />
<br />

<a hide-id="div2">Click here</a>
<div id="div2">
This is content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found to this was to add a check in the eventlistener to check if the href tag was not empty:

`if(curnode.href != '' )`

And only after that firing the redirect:

`location.href = curnode.href;`